# empty path breaks after adding the first app in django

Tags: python, django

I created a new django app and ran it using
`python manage.py runserver` . It ran normal and I could see the default page

[image: normal django welcome screen]

With the shell outputting:

```
Django version 4.0.1, using settings 'storefront.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[23/Jan/2022 18:52:07] ←[m"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 10697←[0m
[23/Jan/2022 18:52:07] ←[36m"GET /static/admin/css/fonts.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0←[0m
[23/Jan/2022 18:52:07] ←[36m"GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Bold-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 304 0←[0m
[23/Jan/2022 18:52:07] ←[36m"GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 304 0←[0m
[23/Jan/2022 18:52:07] ←[36m"GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Light-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 304 0←[0m
Not Found: /favicon.ico
[23/Jan/2022 18:52:07,704] - Broken pipe from ('127.0.0.1', 56807)
```

Then I added a new app, like so:

`python manage.py startapp playground`

then I added an action handler

#### playground/views.py

```
def say_hello(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello World!')
```

I also added `urls.py` inside the `playground` folder

#### playground/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('hello/', views.say_hello)
]
```

And the main `urls.py` I added:

#### root/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('playground/', include('playground.urls')),
]
```

In the main settings.py, I included `playground` in the `INSTALLED_APPS` list.
Then I ran the application, and I can confirm that the path `127.0.0.1:800/playground/hello` works as expected.

However, the empty path `127.0.0.1:8000/` is no longer valid. I get this error:

[image: empty path not working]

The empty path only works if I comment the `playground` urls,

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # once the next line is commented, the empty path works fine
    # path('playground/', include('playground.urls')),
]
```

Here is what the log displays once the empty path is requested:

```
Django version 4.0.1, using settings 'storefront.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Not Found: /
[23/Jan/2022 18:47:36] ←[33m"GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 2174←[0m
Not Found: /favicon.ico
[23/Jan/2022 18:47:36,801] - Broken pipe from ('127.0.0.1', 56786)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is just dummy page as it mentions itself -> 
You're seeing this message because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file and you haven't configured any URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't do anything wrong, the default django page only shows if you don't have any other url patterns to try ([Github](https://github.com/django/django/blob/6815da6e9497a9a630d9f3637a51134d868bcd5b/django/views/debug.py#L544))

Now you need to add a path at `/` or you can just call the django one if you'd prefer

```
from django.views.debug import default_urlconf
path('', default_urlconf)
```

Comment: I added this to the main `urls.py` but the code was not compilable 'path('', default_urlconf)' `SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?`

Comment: Never mind, it turns out, I literally forgot to put a comma.